# Are repeated if-statement constants "reused"? C# .NET

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, constants

It's a simple question, and I cannot believe I have not thought of reading up on it, before now...but I just cannot seem to find the right search terms, to find the answer, so please bear with me:

If I have 60 different if-statements, spread out over several methods throughout my class, like these:

```
if(myVar == 0.0f)
    yaddayadda

if(myOtherVar == 0.0f)
    yaddayadda

if(someVar == 0.0f || someOtherVar == 0.0f)
    yaddayadda
```

...are those 0.0f being put into memory and subsequently GC'ed, every time they're used? Or are they stored in the compiled code? Would I be better off defining something like:

```
const float zero = 0.0f;
```

...and use that instead? If so, is getting a value from a const more expensive CPU-cycle-wise, than just leaving the constant directly in the if-statement?

I ask, because I can see that decimal actually has a decimal.Zero constant, but neither float nor double have one.

Comment: Numbers are not stored in the heap.

Comment: There's no memory being allocated for those if checks, it's just a comparison. BTW, checking equality with 0.0f (or any exact value, really) is bad. Floats are not very accurate, so it's better to check if your variable is below a certain threshold.

Comment: @SLaks The question never uses the word "heap".

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Until you have a deeper understanding of how the GC works, and a profiler, _don't worry about this_.

Comment: @Servy: Except in the term "GC"

Comment: It's obvious when you understand how it works, yet I don't see any quick and simple way to explain... Long story short, value types, such as int or decimal, don't need to be garbage collected. Short story long: you really should read about the .NET memory model, and probably a bit of assembly

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two/

Comment: @itsme86: I know. 0.0f was just an example. It is actually viable to check, if your float-values are not the result of a calculation, or when checking for infinites.

Comment: Constants are not read are runtime. For a compiler to conform to the CLR specification, it must actually replace the use of the constant everywhere in the code and not refer to the constant metadata. The effect then of a constant is actually the same as replacing it with a literal every where it is used in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. That was fast. I am asking, precisely because I'm in the midst of reading up on GC'ing and the .NET memory model, since I have recently started using a profiler, and need to know this stuff :) I just hadn't connected these dots. I have a lot more reading to do.

Comment: Can't comment on the memory issues, but I would recommend it simply due to reusing the same value. Lot easier to edit 1 variable then 60+ fields that all say the same thing.

Comment: @gilliduck: That's only true if they have the same semantic value that may need to be changed (as opposed to zero).

Comment: `0.0` here (regardless of its type and value) are called *literals.* Literals aren't garbage collected because they exist once (and frequently, used a lot).

Comment: @Draco18s That's not true at all.  That something is a literal in no way means it can't be garbage collected.  The type, and value, and usage, is also not irrelevant at all, it's *highly* relevant to if the value is ever going to be GCed.

Comment: @Servy I'd be very interested to see a non-primitive-type literal followed by GC'ing a literal primitive.

Comment: @Draco18s Assign an integer to a field, keep no references to the object with the field, that field, and the value you allocated with your literal, gets GCed.  Or, even more straightforward, turn of string interning and then every string literal you ever create gets GCed (unless they're still alive when the whole program completes).

Comment: @Servy If there's no references to it, I expect the compiler to not even bother putting it into the binary. As for program termination: the memory is going to get freed no matter what GC says about it (and actually, yes, I would expect that value to persist in memory: freed memory does not *necessarily* hold the value of 0 which is why array-index-out-of-bounds causes undefined behavior).

Comment: @Draco18s If you construct an object and then don't hold onto a reference to it then no, the compiler can't just not construct it.  It still has to construct it.  The program termination is just me saying that the GC has to actually run for the objects in my example to get GCed.  If the program terminates before the GC runs the memory is freed, but not by the GC, it's just all cleaned up when the OS tears down the process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146574/discussion-between-draco18s-and-servy).

Comment: The code pattern you are showing is "hard-coding" repeated values.  Everywhere there's a reference to 0.0F instead is should reference a variable for maintainability.  GC works in three passes, mostly controlled by vars. being in-scope of a method.  Once the method is complete, the vars are marked as eligible for GC.  What happens from there is magic.

Comment: @JohnPeters I'd caution against creating a common variable to hold a value just because it's the same common value for the reason that SLaks mentioned above (semantics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference. The compiled version would be the same.

Take a look at the [design guidlines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/field):

> The compiler burns the values of const fields directly into calling
>   code. Therefore, const values can never be changed without the risk of
>   breaking compatibility.

Comment: So, I should only create a const field, for a frequently checked/used constant, if the value of that constant, is likely to change between builds, and I want to be able to make such a change, by only changing the value in one place, the const field. Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @UltromantheTacoman as long as the const is `internal` visible. `Public` visible const should never ever change, because, you need to rebuild the whole dependencies (since the calls to the const are directly replaced inline by the literal).

Comment: That is an excellent point! I'll remember to make my const's internal, when applicable.